# Setting text to array of edit text android

Tags: android, arrays, android-edittext

I  have an array of  text which is dynamically generated and when user clicks a button , I need each character of particular string to get displayed in each  text.

For eg. my  text looks like,

[image: output]

where each'-' represents an  text and when user clicks a button , I want a string/character to get populated each time . For. eg, when user clicks button for first time, I want character 'a' to get displayed .So, my  text array must look lik

```
a - -
```

and when user clicks for the second time, I must populate 'b' in second  text field, So, output must be,

```
a b -
```

and the values 'a' and 'b' are dynamic. I have tried using below code,

```
            EditText[] editText = new EditText[dynamiclen];
            for (int n = 0; n < dynamiclen; n++) {
                editText[n] = new EditText(PuzzleWithHint.this);

                editText[n].setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                        (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                editText[n].setFocusable(true);
                editText[n].setImeOptions(editText[n].getImeOptions() | EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                editText[n].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                editText[n].setTextColor((Color.parseColor("#E3732D")));
                editText[n].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                editText[n].setText(ansstring);
                editText[n].setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});
                allEds.add(editText[n]);
                gl.addView(editText[n]);
            }
            editText[1].getText().clear();
            editText[2].getText().clear();
            hintcount++;
            Log.d(tag, "hintcc" + hintcount);
```

Any help would be great !! Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: Initially I am setting value for all the edit text and am just trying to clear the text of edit text based on static integer value "hintcount" @Egor

Comment: Any error you getting or not work code?

Comment: When I click the button for first time, the output is like, a - - . Then when I click for second time, its like, b-- . the Texts are getting populated in same edit text @AjayPandya

Comment: you adding all edittext in array dont set text at start. set text on button click using edittext store in arraylist